# Listener Status Blocked

Tags: linux, oracle, listener, dataguard

I'm deploying a 12C dataguard on oracle.
When performing all procedures, start the instance in the standby, as nomount. I noticed that the standby listener is as BLOCKED status, making it impossible for connections in the database to make Duplicate through rman, it does not allow because of the blocked status of the listener.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

A NOMOUNT instance stays in BLOCKED status with dynamic registration. You need to use static registration to connect a NOMOUNT instance remotely.

Add the below to `listener.ora` and restart the listener:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER=
(SID_LIST=
 (SID_DESC=
  (GLOBAL_DBNAME=ORCL)
  (SID_NAME=ORCL)
  (ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1)
 )
)
```

Of course, change the values of variables accordingly to your environment.